# What is this alphabet slider called on Green's Dictionary of Slang?

Tags: sliders

I came across this website called Green's Dictionary of Slang and thought the alphabet slider was pretty neat. It shows the first word on the page for that portion of the slider you're hovering.  I want to incorporate it in one of my websites but I have no idea what it's called so I don't know what to research.  Anyone see this before?

[image]

https://greensdictofslang.com/browse/

Answer (score 1):

It's called an alphabetical list and I personally find it extremely uncomfortable to use, especially with big amounts of data, i.e. dictionaries or big phone books.

Comment: Do you have any reference for this? I'd like to find other examples but  searching for "alphabetical list", "alphabetical list slider", "alphabetical list plugin" isn't returning anything.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, which is why I came here.  I feel like it exists out there, but I haven't seen it until now.  Also, I would be using it with mediawiki and our wiki doesn't have a massive amount of pages.

Comment: Are you interested in this particular presentation or any alphabetical list? They can vary in presentation. It's just an index, Apple iOS has one in their phone book.

Comment: I'd say to qualify as an answer for this question it has to meet three criteria   1) Be a list of letters 2) Be a hover/slider 3) Show the first word popover. If it doesn't meet all the criteria because it's a one off customization I think it should say that for example, standard alphabetical lists meet #1, but were customized to meet #2 + #3. If the iOS one is a slider too say that this is an iOS slider customized to meet #3. etc.

Comment: @DasBeasto, you totally confused me right there. It is what it is. It is an alphabetical list (or index), it arranges data in alphabetical order and allows you to navigate to a particular part of that list.

Comment: @IvanVenediktov sorry for the confusion. I simply meant that OP specifically asked for an alphabetical slider that "shows the first word on the page for that portion of the slider you're hovering"  which this answer does not cover. If there is no better name for this type of element I believe this answer should at least say its a "souped up alphabetical list".

Comment: @DasBeasto, let me correct you, OP asked "What is this alphabet slider called on Green's Dictionary of Slang?" and I gave him the answer to his question.

Comment: @IvanVenediktov an incomplete answer at best as the only similarity is that it has the alphabet on it.

Comment: @DasBeasto, ok, you are right. Please edit my answer to meet your criteria.